# How to change gradlew .env file?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew

I have a react native project.

I want to build a release to publish on play store, here in react native official [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-aab) to publish an app we can see:

> ### Generating the release AAB
>
> Run the following in a terminal:
>
> ```bash
> cd android
> ./gradlew bundleRelease
> ```

Here is the first outputs I got:

```bash
./gradlew bundleRelease
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env
```

`gradlew` is reading my env vars in `.env` file while I got a `.env.production` that I want `gradlew` to read instead.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) if you want to use other type of .env files for different environments.